# mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in

Tags: php, mysqli

/the cart table has 4 fields; id, username, product id, image. I am trying show all the data in a table.

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user_name='$username'";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query)) {

    /* execute statement */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$username);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($row=mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) 

{
```

Comment: Why prepare a query if you're not binding the input?

Comment: You haven't understand how prepared statements work. The goal of it is to replace your `$username` with a placeholder. After that, you bind a variable to that placeholder. You should google for an example of a prepared statement and change your code according to it.

Comment: You should get in the habit of [accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that provides you with the best solution.  
This website works both ways, and if you don't give back to the people that help you, you won't be getting much help in the future. 
You also gain reputation for accepting answers. @Mirthful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are, as far as I can see, two issues here

1. You're not binding your *input* - this is the whole point of prepared statements. You need `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`. Injecting variables directly in the query is not safe, and is why we prepare our queries.
2. You're not binding the exact amount of columns selected with `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()`. This needs to be the exact amount of columns you select.

To make this work, you need to use placeholders `?` in the query instead of variables (and use `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`). You should also select the specific columns, and not do `SELECT *`. If you do `SELECT *`, you can still make it work if you still bind the same amount of results - but the code will break if you add one column at a later time.

This code below has been altered to select the specific columns, and match that with as many results you bind (columns) in `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()`. A placeholder in the query has been added, and usage of `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` implemented.

```
$query = "SELECT id, user_name, produc_id, image FROM cart WHERE user_name=?";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query)) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param("s", $username);

    /* execute statement */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id, $username, $product_id, $image);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($row=mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        // Fetch here
    }
}
```

- [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
- [`mysqli_stmt::bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think your call to `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` is incorrect. I recommend two things:

1. enumerate your columns in the text of your SQL statement
2. pass one PHP variable for each column that you specify.

The way your `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` is written, the code will only work if the table has one column, user_name.